# Unable to compile Qt Creator App for Android Build

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to build a QT app for Android. I have the JDK, SDK and the NDK setup already using QT.
[Android Setup in QT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmecV.png)

When I try to build the app, I get the **error**:

```
C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang no such file or directory.
```

Which makes sense - as when I checked the SDK folder - the `clang.exe` file is in a different path:

```
"C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe"
```

My issue is that QT is automatically detecting compilers and the former path is defined for it. I don't see the option to edit the path., or rather the option is there but it wont let me edit the path. How can I modify the path for the compiler so that QT can find the compiler?

Compiler path: `d\Sdk\ndk\21.3.652814\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe`

Details:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your existing compiler by clicking the `Clone` button (between `Add` and `Remove` buttons on the right side button bar) when the compiler is selected in `Compilers` view. Manually added compilers can be edited so you can change the compiler path. [image: Clone button]

Then you select `Kits` and select your manually added compiler as a compiler of the kit. I assume you need to manually create both C and C++ compilers [image]

No idea what went wrong with the compiler auto-detection in your case. You can see in the first screenshot that my auto-detected compiler points to the correct location.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I re-installed the SDK, this time from Android Studio. I get the correct path for it. I'm also able to build the QT examples. But when I try to build my app i still get the same error as earlier:

Comment: error:
/usr/bin/sh: C:UsersaryanAppDataLocalAndroidSdkndk21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:2411: armeabi-v7a/qrc_qgroundcontrol.obj] Error 127
17:21:35: The process "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited with code 2.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot about your kit tab to your original question? Also project pro  file or CMakeLists.txt would be helpful. Maybe you built Qt examples with ARM compiler and that worked. I wonder why you are building with x86-64 compiler...